# Select Checkbutton due to config.ini values Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How i can check Checkbutton in Tkinter due to value from config.ini
From parsing Config I recieve 1 or 0

```
def show_config():
    config = switcher.config_read()
    setting = Toplevel(root)
    setting.title = 'Setting Change'
    setting.geometry('320x620')
    top = Frame(setting)
    top.pack(side=TOP)
    sections1 = Label(top, text='section1')
    sections1.pack()
    btn1= IntVar(value=1)
    btn2= IntVar()
    btn2.set(1)
    btn1_check = Checkbutton(top, text='btn1', variable=btn1)
    btn2_check = Checkbutton(top, text='btn1', variable=btn2)
    btn1_check.pack(side=LEFT)
    btn2_check.pack(side=LEFT)
```

I tried `btn1= IntVar(value=1)` and `btn2.set(1)` the Checkbutton  were unchecked

Comment: both syntax should work, could you add more code to show how the widgets are displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the scope of the function that get garbage collected.

The following code cannot work :

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def show_config():
    check = tk.IntVar(value=1)
    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="check", variable=check)
    checkbox.pack()
show_config()
root.mainloop()
```

This one can get the value set by your config :

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

check = tk.IntVar(value=1)
checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="check", variable=check)
checkbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you are using classes it can be easy to keep the variables (with `self.btn1`), otherwise you might use globals.

---

A possible workaround :

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
check=None

def show_config():
    global check
    check = tk.IntVar(value=1)
    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="check", variable=check)
    checkbox.pack()
show_config()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: but i have a menu button `main_menu.add_command(label='Setting', command=show_config)` which call `show_config` in `Toplevel` window with ode that i posted. Config won't be shown when the programs starts only if setting was cliked

Comment: @Hellbea Then try to declare the variables btn1 and btn2 outside the function, as global

Comment: @Hellbea i edited a workaround, globals are not very pretty, but don't change your whole project for this

Comment: I just starting it and i will try to rewrite to class. Big thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `IntVar()` which can basically hold any integer value I would suggest using a `BooleanVar()` which can hold `True`/`False` or `1`/`0`, respectively. Calling `.set()` on the variable modifies its value to the passed one. Following snippet shows setting `BooleanVar()` using both 'direct' approach with `.set(True)` and indirect approach with simulated config file (`dict`):

```
from tkinter import *


def read_config(file_name):
    # read config from file system
    # return statement needs to be modified to own needs
    return {'check_btn_var': 1}


config = read_config('<file_name>')

master = Tk()


# use config from config file for checkbutton cb1
var1 = BooleanVar()
var1.set(config.get('check_btn_var'))

cb1 = Checkbutton(master, text="Checkbutton", variable=var1)
cb1.pack()


# use hard coded value for checkbutton cb2
var2 = BooleanVar()
var2.set(True)

cb2 = Checkbutton(master, text="Checkbutton", variable=var2)
cb2.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: same. it maybe cause i use `def show_config():` and call it by `main_menu.add_command(label='Setting', command=show_config)` and this button call `Toplevel` window where the `Checkbutton` must be checked. But it didn't even i put `true` or `1` manually